# Cell Value Based on Multiple Cells

Tags: excel

I know there has to be a way to achieve what I am wanting to do.
I have 4 cells: A1, B1, C1, D1. If any of these cells contains a "Y", I want E1 to display a "Y".
Ex: A1="", B1="Y", C1="", D1="Y". Then E1="Y".

Comment: [`OR` function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/or-function-7d17ad14-8700-4281-b308-00b131e22af0)

Comment: =IF(OR(A1="Y",B1="Y",C1="Y",D1="Y"),"Y","")

Comment: GSerg not sure why I didn't think of that - Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may try-

```
=IF(OR(A1:D1="Y"),"Y","")
```

[image]

Comment: I tried using your formula, I'm getting a "#VALUE!".

Comment: If you are not on Excel-365 then try to enter the formula as array entry with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`.

Comment: @BrentJohn have you considered your system settings ie that "," might be ";" ?

Answer (score 0):

as mention above but more "complex", you can use this formula too:

```
=IF(A1="Y","Y",IF(B1="Y","Y",IF(C1="Y","Y",IF(D1="Y","Y",""))))
```

[image: Look at this picture]